# soundcloud api and web audio api not working together

Tags: javascript, audio, soundcloud, web-audio-api

Today, I've added a way to allow users to use soundcloud musics on the website, except that it only works when I remove the analyser generated by the web audio api.

here's the code that appends the soundcloud link to the audio tags:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13 && $("#customSong").is(":focus")){
        var customSongLink = $("#customSong").val();

        SC.get('/resolve', { url: customSongLink }, function(sound) {
            SC.get("/tracks/" + sound.id, {}, function(sound){
                $("#Musique").attr("src", sound.uri+"/stream?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID" );

                $(".mediaName").html("<span></span>");
                $(".mediaName span").html(sound.user.username+" - "+sound.title);
                $(".mediaName").textfill();
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and here's the code for the visualizer:

```
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bar_x, bar_height;
function initVisualizer() {
    context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    biquad = context.createBiquadFilter();
    gainNode = context.createGain();
    canvas = document.getElementById("visualizer");
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#3f3f3f";


    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
    biquad.frequency.value = 15000;
    gainNode.gain.value = 1;

    source = context.createMediaElementSource(Musique);
    source.connect(biquad);
    biquad.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    $("#frequencyNumber").html(biquad.frequency.value);
    $("#visualizerSensibilityNumber").html(analyser.smoothingTimeConstant);
    $("#gainNumber").html(gainNode.gain.value.toPrecision(3));

    framelooper()
}

function framelooper() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(framelooper);
    fbcArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbcArray);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (i=0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * bar_x_spaces + 0.5;
        bar_height = -(fbcArray[i] / bar_height_sensibility);

        if (visualizerStyle == 1){
            //Simple
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Simple");
        }
        else if (visualizerStyle == 2) {
            //Reflection
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, bar_height/2);
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, -bar_height/2);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Reflection");
        }
        else {
            //Two-faced
            ctx.fillRect(0, bar_x, -bar_height, bar_width);
            ctx.fillRect(canvas.width, bar_x, bar_height, bar_width);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Face to Face");
        }
    }
}
```

[website with the issue (double click on the song title to make the input box appear, enter a soundcloud link inside)](http://googledrive.com/host/0ByBwY60ZsbQpZjFJaDhTQlRfdTg/)

**Edit: I found out that the problem is due to a change in the cross-origin of audio files, I've also seen a lot of people say that adding "crossOrigin = anonymous" fixes it, but it didn't for me.**

**does it only do that for some music, or is it no longer a possible fix?**

**if it's the later, is there any other fix?**

Comment: this is just a bunch of files I've uploaded on google drive, so I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough for you to set crossOrigin.  The server must also allow cross-origin access by returning appropriate headers.  This is probably not in your control.

Comment: how would you do that, just to be sure

Comment: You'd have to ask soundcloud about that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like without the SDK and without createMediaElementSource it will work.

Thats the way i load the sample from SoundCloud.

```
function SCkickOffSampleDownload( sample ) {
    var url = new URL(sample+ '?client_id=679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function() {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData( request.response,
        function(buffer) {
          console.log("sample loaded!");
          sample.loaded=true;
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.start(0);
          initVisualizer();          
      },
      function() { console.log("Decoding error! ");} );
    }
    sample.loaded = false;
    request.send();
  }
```

Here is a fiddle with almost your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/8qw5511L/

EDIT 1:

```
$(function() {
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7"
  });

var scurl = 'https://soundcloud.com/bnzlovesyou/daktari-preview';
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bar_x, bar_height;
var visualizerColor = "#3f3f3f";
var bars = 50;
var bar_x_spaces = 6;
var bar_width = 4;
var bar_height_sensibility = 1.75;
var visualizerStyle = 1;

audioContext = new AudioContext();
var source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
var gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
source.connect(gainNode);
gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;

function SCkickOffSampleDownload( sample ) {
    var url = new URL(sample+ '?client_id=679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function() {
      audioContext.decodeAudioData( request.response,
        function(buffer) {
          console.log("sample loaded!");
          sample.loaded=true;
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.start(0);
          initVisualizer();          
      },
      function() { console.log("Decoding error! ");} );
    }
    sample.loaded = false;
    request.send();
  }

function initVisualizer() {
 //   context = new AudioContext();
    analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    biquad = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
    gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
    canvas = document.getElementById("visualizer");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#3f3f3f";


    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.8;
    biquad.frequency.value = 15000;
    gainNode.gain.value = 1;

    source.connect(biquad);
    biquad.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);

    $("#frequencyNumber").html(biquad.frequency.value);
    $("#visualizerSensibilityNumber").html(analyser.smoothingTimeConstant);
    $("#gainNumber").html(gainNode.gain.value.toPrecision(3));

    framelooper()
}

function framelooper() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(framelooper);
    fbcArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbcArray);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (i=0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * bar_x_spaces + 0.5;
        bar_height = -(fbcArray[i] / bar_height_sensibility);

        if (visualizerStyle == 1){
            //Simple
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Simple");
        }
        else if (visualizerStyle == 2) {
            //Reflection
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, bar_height/2);
            ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height/2, bar_width, -bar_height/2);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Reflection");
        }
        else {
            //Two-faced
            ctx.fillRect(0, bar_x, -bar_height, bar_width);
            ctx.fillRect(canvas.width, bar_x, bar_height, bar_width);
            $("#visualizerStyleType").html("Face to Face");
        }
    }
}


SC.get('/resolve', { url: scurl }, function(sound) {
       SCkickOffSampleDownload( sound.stream_url );
        });

});
```

Working example that SoundCloud and webaudio api working together.
I took the files from your drive.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/e3zxby88/

Comment: I have the code o google drive and I get this error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://5a0409b6129ff21bdaa69aae95690807eb6e5482.googledrive.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: have u tried the code? here is the fiddle on drive: https://googledrive.com/host/0B0TM6mPwlvfkQ0RkeHZXN3Flek0

Comment: yup, on the site, when you type the link in the input box and hit enter, it give this error in the console, this is what customSong.js looks like: http://pastebin.com/JKk63EWt

Comment: i guess the error must be different, because it does not do resolve for you.

Comment: also, with this solution, would my media player still work (would I be able to move around with the timeline, change the volume,...)

Comment: yes, but you have to rewrite some parts, taking care that your audio source has been changed - ie initvisualizer function. here is a fiddle with resolving, i hope this will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/xn2nuwv2/

Comment: I have added another example, with some of your files. Hardcoded scurl, http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/e3zxby88/